# Placement of the clause "more than once"

Tags: grammar

Is:

> "We saw the fatal cliff **more than once**, from which the climber fell to his death."

the correct form of the sentence:

> "We saw the fatal cliff from which the climber fell to his death **more than once**."?

The former sentence sounds a bit awkward? Is there any alternative?

Comment: *More than once we saw the fatal cliff...* or *We more than once saw...* do a better job of keeping the right pieces together.

Comment: In its current form it sounds like he fell to his death multiple times.

Comment: We repeatedly saw the fatal cliff from which the climber fell to his death.

Comment: @Blue that's actually a good example of the *misplaced modifier* since the placement of "more than once" makes it sound like the climber had multiple fatal accidents.

Comment: Why not just put the time statement up front? "*More than once* we saw the fatal cliff from which the climber fell to his death." I doubt any of these positions is wrong without detailed context.

Answer (score 0):

While you can describe a cliff as *fatal* the usage is figurative and poetic, and not common in ordinary conversation.  Example:

> There were three of us who set out that **fatal day**.

This is appropriate for a dramatic tale, especially since it creates *tension* to have the narrator say someone is going to die later in the story.

Otherwise you could say *"the cliff where the climber **took a fatal fall**"* or *"The cliff where the climber **plunged to his death**"*.

So, with that out of the way: I'm not sure how it sounds in another language but to me I'd want to know *why* you returned to that cliff.  Without explanation it sounds a little strange and implies some weird, morbid curiosity.

Instead I would choose a phrase like "We returned to the cliff where ..." or "We revisited the cliff where ..." in order to at least *imply* intention, or even to lead into an explanation.

Putting the pieces together:

> We **went back, more than once,** to that cliff where the climber **had suffered his fatal accident** some weeks before (*in order to pay our respects | to complete our investigation | out of a strange fascination with the scene | etc*).

Answer (score 0):

I try to keep modifiers as close as practicable to the words they modify, so I would write:

> We saw more than once the fatal cliff from which the climber fell to his death.

or

> More than once, we saw the fatal cliff from which the climber fell to his death.